# M2_REPO and m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've spent many hours searching and wonder why is this so hard to get it to work?! Browsing through different questions regarding this have not led me to an answer.

I have a multi-project multi-module application, i.e. I import two projects each having several modules. Now the generated sources cannot be found/inferred,

**eclipse displays them as missing types**.
**I can build from command line but Eclipse cannot find the class files.**

I have set M2_REPO in Window->Preferences->Maven... also I point out an external Maven install in Eclipse.

What could be wrong? I do get
**"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugin"**

for some POMs but I'm not sure if that is related to the problem at all.

Comment: Have you tried running mvn eclipse:clean and mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Comment: If you get that error, you're probably running m2e, not m2eclipse (which is older), so you should update the question and tags

Comment: @AmitBhargava I don't think that is necessary as I import the project by pointing out the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

See [m2e wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#execute_plugin_goal) for adding custom build lifecycle mapping for Eclipse.